# Android Studio and Flutter - possible to have web enabled in one project but not in other?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-web

I'm writing an app for iOS and Android which has a companion web app. Rather than mess about with writing the web app separately in HTML and JS (which I have very little experience in), I figured I'd write it in Flutter too.

In order to do this, I have had to go onto a Flutter beta-branch. This fundamentally breaks my iOS/Android app, with dozens of errors which weren't there before (some really odd stuff too!) - so is there a way to **turn off** web support or force Android Studio to look at different branches of Flutter in order to protect against this so I can develop the apps side by side?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option: manage flutter versions by hand**

1. Switch to the *master* branch on your current flutter version and clone beta branch to another directory.
2. Add new path (`flutterb` for instance) and point it to the directory with flutter beta.
3. In Android Studio go to File > Settings >Languages & Frameworks > Flutter and change the path to point to flutter beta. It changes that settings globally, so you need to change it each time unfortunately.

**Second option: try [Flutter Version Management](https://pub.dev/packages/fvm)** - recommended one